# mount device and md5sum is changed

Tags: mount, ext4, hashsum, slackware

If mount `sdc2` partition using `mount -t ext4 -o ro /dev/sdc2 /mnt/bob2` then try to write file `tihi 1.txt` with command (of course unsuccessfully):

```
touch /mnt/bob2/ tihi 1.txt
```

When I do `md5sum /dev/sdc2/`, I get a different md5 hash (changed) than before, although my partition is read-only, I don't know why.

Comment: if it works with `mount -o loop,ro` it's because ext4 writes even in ro mode

Comment: md5sum on a directory generally does not work (can work with recursive mode). Double check your commands and arguments to those commands. `touch /mnt/bob2 tihi 1.txt` affects **three** paths, not one. So add some quotes. Also include the md5sum checksum which is different between runs.

Comment: @frostschutz What are you talking about?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96508/30851 " the system may still write to the device "

Comment: Is `/dev/sdc2/` a typo? The trailing slash makes no sense.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин "Also include the md5sum checksum which is different between runs" why? you can't tell what changed

Comment: @Bravo because I want to know that the author of the question is interpreting the data correctly.

Comment: at a guess, I'd say since the ext4 filesystem superblock includes a `Mount time, in seconds since the epoch.` - the act of mounting it would, by definition, update that

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин - seeing md5sum has changed doesn't take 4 years of computing science :p - OP states it's different and has changed - what more is there to say

Comment: @Bravo neither does invoking a command on a single file with spaces, correctly.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин - true - also the `md5sum` command as shown wouldn't even run - guess the whole question is impossible